# How to add connection-timeout property to Spring MVC poject?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, timeout, connection-timeout

I have a spring MVC project (5.0.5.RELEASE) and I would like to add a configuration to consider timeout. My project has a controller and I send request using postman. So the idea is to kill the execution when timeout. Besides I like to handle the exception to preparete a custom message error

How can i do that?

Answer (score -1):

you will be having **UserController** or **TokenUtils** class for generating token

so the below code one of the class time out or expire the connection

```
public static String createToken(UserDetails userDetails)
{
    /* Expires in three hour */
    long expires = System.currentTimeMillis() + 1000L * 60 * 180;

    StringBuilder tokenBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    tokenBuilder.append(userDetails.getUsername());
    tokenBuilder.append(":");
    tokenBuilder.append(expires);
    tokenBuilder.append(":");
    tokenBuilder.append(TokenUtils.computeSignature(userDetails, expires));

    return tokenBuilder.toString();
}
```

i hope its helps you